How to restrict single photo selection while photo library access permission is displayed and user selects allow access?
In my SwiftUI application user should is allowed select only one photo from photo gallery. When first time application is installed and it asks for App would like to access your photo libary pop up and user selects limited access at in  photo list user can select multiple photos(though it would not be selected on click of done). I want to restrict it to selecting only photo is it possible. Below code works fine in all other scenarios. I think as it is iOS generated permission popup such restriction would not be possible. Any help on this would be appreciated.
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var imagePickerIsPresented: Bool = false
    @State var imageWasImported: Bool = false

    @State var image: UIImage = UIImage()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100,height: 150)
            Button("Select Photo") {
                self.requestAccess()
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $imagePickerIsPresented, content: {
            ImagePicker(imageToImport: $image, isPresented: $imagePickerIsPresented, imageWasImported: $imageWasImported)
        })
    }
    
    func requestAccess() {
        let accessLevel: PHAccessLevel = .readWrite
        let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus(for: accessLevel)
        
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            self.imagePickerIsPresented.toggle()
        case .limited:
            print("Limited access - show picker.")
            self.imagePickerIsPresented.toggle()
        case .denied:
            print("Access denied")
        case .notDetermined:
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { newStatus in
                switch newStatus {
                case .authorized:
                    print("Full access.")
                case .limited:
                    print("Limited access.")
                    break
                case .denied:
                    break
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        default:
            break
            
            
        }

    }
    
}
#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var imageToImport: UIImage
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Binding var imageWasImported: Bool
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> some UIViewController {
        
        var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
        configuration.filter = .images
        configuration.selectionLimit = 1
        
        let imagePicker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return imagePicker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ImagePicker.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePicker.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
        
        var parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)
            
            if results.count != 1 {
                return
            }
            
            if let image = results.first {
                
                
                if image.itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
                    image.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, error  in
                        
                        if let image = image {
                            self.parent.imageToImport = image as! UIImage
                            self.parent.imageWasImported.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            self.parent.isPresented.toggle()
        }
    }
}


you could try using PhotosPicker, see
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/bringing_photos_picker_to_your_swiftui_app
For example, the call with a maxSelectionCount parameter:
PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedPhotos, maxSelectionCount: 1, matching: .images) {             Label("Select a photo", systemImage: "photo")         }

Yes, use photospicker if you can.  No need to ask for permissions and a much nicer experience for the user

Change it to @State var image: UIImage? and set it to nil onDisappear to avoid memory leak.
